# How to build tree from array in JavaScript where first level items have non-empty id?

Tags: javascript

There's a lot of posts on Stackoverflow that discuss building tree from array in JavaScript. I've tried some of them, but without success.

We have Vue 3 app and I need to display items' names in select box. The input array of objects looks as following:

[image]

As you can see, there are, for example, two items. First one is parent and second one is its child. The parentUUID of child item is the same as uuid of its parent. The number of levels of items could be >= 1.

How should we build the tree? We select some node (item) in separate tree view and select box should be filled out with all tree items except for selected node (item) and all its children. It can be multiple levels under selected node (item).

We use the same input array for populating tree view and for select box. I think the select box could be populated from tree structure built from input array, of course without selected item and its children. Maybe there's some another, easier way (not using tree structure), but I'm not sure. If there's another way, please, suggest.

ADDITIONAL:

[image]

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve, maybe some code sample could help. If what you really want is building a tree-like data structure from the array above (with parent child relations expressed with uuid and parentUUID) then the problem is trivial. What you do with it is not clear here.

Comment: I think with tree structure I would be able to remove any node with all its children easier. That's all I need. If there is another way, not building the tree, it could be nice.

Comment: See my answer to build a tree structure from an array like the one in your screenshot

Comment: Please don't post data as a screenshot. Provide the structured data as text in JSON format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that it is what you're trying to achieve but assuming it is only building a tree from the array above, the algorithm could be as follow:

```js
// source structure:
// { uuid, parentUUID, ...restOfyournodedata }[]
// target structure:
// interface TreeNode { data: yournodedata, children: TreeNode[] }

const sourceData = [
  { uuid: 'rootid', parentUUID: null /* or empty */, /* rest of data doesn't matter */ },
  { uuid: 'child0.0', parentUUID: 'rootid' },
  { uuid: 'child0.1', parentUUID: 'rootid' },
  { uuid: 'child0.2', parentUUID: 'rootid' },
  { uuid: 'child0.0.0', parentUUID: 'child0.0' },
  { uuid: 'child0.0.1', parentUUID: 'child0.0' },
  { uuid: 'child0.0.2', parentUUID: 'child0.0' },
  { uuid: 'child0.1.0', parentUUID: 'child0.1' },
  { uuid: 'child0.1.1', parentUUID: 'child0.1' },
  { uuid: 'child0.2.0', parentUUID: 'child0.2' },
];

/**
 * @param {typeof sourceData} source
 * @param {TreeNode[]} currentChildren
 * @param {string | null | undefined} currentUUID
 * */
function buildTree(source, currentChildren, currentUUID) {
  // collect from source the elements with parentUUID === currentUUID
  const elements = source.filter(elem => elem.parentUUID === currentUUID);
  elements.forEach(elem => {
    // build a treenode for this element
    const treeNode = {
      data: elem,
      children: []
    };
    // add it to the parent children array
    currentChildren.push(treeNode);
    // continue recursively, it will stop when no element with the specified parentUUID can be found
    buildTree(source, treeNode.children, elem.uuid)
  })
}

const result = []
buildTree(sourceData, result, null);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

**EDIT:**
If having a null parentUUID is NOT the condition to be a root node we just need to define this condition and collect root nodes first, then populate their children:

```js
const rootNodes = [/* root elements */.....].map(elem => ({ data: elem, children: [] }));

rootNodes.forEach(rootNode => buildTree(sourceData, rootNode.children, rootNode.data.uuid));
```

Let's say rootNodes are the ones for which the parentUUID does not match any other element:

```js
const rootNodes = sourceData.filter(
    elem => !sourceData.some(
        elem2 => elem.parentUUID === elem2.uuid
    )
).map(elem => ({ data: elem, children: [] }));

rootNodes.forEach(rootNode => buildTree(sourceData, rootNode.children, rootNode.data.uuid));
```

Let's say rootNodes are the ones for which the parentUUID === a specific parentUUID:

```js
const rootUUID = 'whatever you want';
const rootNodes = sourceData.filter(
    elem => elem.parentUUID === rootUUID 
).map(elem => ({ data: elem, children: [] }));

rootNodes.forEach(rootNode => buildTree(sourceData, rootNode.children, rootNode.data.uuid));
```

Comment: The result array is empty in my case. There could be multiple root nodes with non-empty  parentUUID. These parentUUIDs are not null. They are left after some another operation.

Comment: If the parentUUID of a root node is not null and not empty. What makes it a root node? Is it the fact that no element with the designated uuid exists? whatever the criteria is, if it's not havong a null parentUUID, we just need to polutate the root nodes first, then look for children

Comment: Please, take a look at the screenshot in ADDITIONAL section of my post.

Comment: It still doesn't tell what makes them root nodes. See my edit if it helps

Comment: The same parentUUID.

Comment: Then collect the root elements according to this parentUUID. Adding a new edit....

Comment: How can I console.log the result in case of second and third edit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255424/discussion-between-remix23-and-tesicg).